# Simple SQL query to display orders from a specific city with multiple tables, needing a Head of Knowledge

Tags: sql

The question asks, "Show ID, name and total dollar amount of orders for customers  located in Boston. (label amount as “TotalPurchase”) (Dollar amount of an order is calculated by “Quantity * SalePrice”

When I run the query I get an error stating, "Your query does not include the specified expression 'CID' as part of an aggregate function". Can anyone help me out or explain why I am getting this error?

Also, do i need to join the tables, am i referencing them correctly?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT Customer.CID Customer.Name, Customer.City, OrderT.CID, OrderItem.ItemID, 
       SUM(OrderItem.Quantity * OrderItem.SalePrice) as TotalPurchase
FROM Customer, OrderT, OrderItem, Inventory
GROUP BY Customer.City=’Boston’;
```

and here is a image of the database
[image]

Comment: Google all of these, in order; `INNER JOIN`, `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Note, it's a lot easier if you just provide an output of the database instead of screen prints, which are a little small and hard to read.  This way people can reproduce your issues.  (Note, I'm not sure if that was a transition issue while copying and pasting your query, but there are smart quotes;  those will break your query)

Comment: @nomistic how do i provide an output of the database instead of screen prints?

Comment: Well the syntax varies depending on the database.  In mysql it is `mysqldump --databases test > dump.sql`.   In postgresql it is `pg_dump dbname > outfile`.  Look up the documentation for your specific one.  It will output to a text file (usually with a .sql extension), and you can paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a SQL query with a GROUP BY clause, you need to include every non-aggregated field you have in your SELECT clause (i.e. the fields you aren't using SUM() on) in the GROUP BY clause or you'll get this error.

For your specific example, you'll want to do a:

```
WHERE Customer.City = 'Boston'
```

instead of a

```
GROUP BY Customer.City = 'Boston'
```

And your GROUP BY should be:

```
GROUP BY Customer.CID, Customer.Name
```

As far as joins, you can do your query with or without them. I'll show both syntax's below:

Without Joins:

```
SELECT
    Customer.CID,
    Customer.Name,
    SUM(OrderItem.Quantity * OrderItem.SalePrice) as TotalPurchase
FROM Customer, OrderT, OrderItem
WHERE
    Customer.CID = OrderT.CID
    AND
    OrderT.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
    AND
    Customer.City = 'Boston'
GROUP BY
    Customer.CID,
    Customer.Name
```

With Joins:

```
SELECT
    Customer.CID,
    Customer.Name,
    SUM(OrderItem.Quantity * OrderItem.SalePrice) as TotalPurchase
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN OrderT ON Customer.CID = OrderT.CID
INNER JOIN OrderItem ON OrderT.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
WHERE
    Customer.City = 'Boston'
GROUP BY
    Customer.CID,
    Customer.Name
```